# Mapping with and without /

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

I use spring boot, thymeleaf, tomcat

I give 3 case of call server from ajax call

case 1
ajax url:
/sampling

mvc (mapping)
sampling

that work

case 2
ajax  url:
sampling

mvc (mapping)
sampling

that don't work

case 3
ajax  url:
/sampling

mvc (mapping)
/sampling

that work

why case 1 is working, on the server, / is not where....

is it better to use case 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Case 1* and *Case 3* are essentially the same because:

- Their respective AJAX request URLs are the same
- Their request mappings are the same since Controller base mapping is the same and there is no difference whether you write leading / (slash) or not at the controller method level

*Case 2* is a different AJAX request URL so you can not hit any controller method for that.

Using Case 3 is better because of the writing habits and readability. For some other complex controller method url mappings you should always make it like Case 3. If you look at the examples of Controllers than you will see Case 3 kind of usage all over.